# Changing jobs from UK tier 2 to UK tier 2

Tags: uk-visa

I have given 1 month notice, so by my calculations HMRC will give me ~90-100 days to stay in the UK. While this happens I'm waiting for my new employer to organise the [job suitability](https://www.gov.uk/uk-visa-sponsorship-employers/job-suitability) test and get the certificate of sponsorship.

A few questions:

1. If my legal time in UK expires, can I simply wait in any country, or will I need to go back to Australia for some paperwork (or biometrics)
2. While on my notice period I have a week or so of "garden leave". Am I legally allowed to work the [20hr 2nd job until](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general/second-job) at my new place up until I get the notice of visa termination from the HMRC?

Comment: A T2 can only be applied for in the country of your nationality (UNLIKE the case for visitor visas). You can work the 2nd job ONLY IF the job description is the same as your current T2.  HMRC does not send the curtailment noice, UKVI sends it (a different directorate). Also you can work the 2nd job after the curtailment notice is sent, but not after the curtailment date.

Comment: Another note: if you apply in country **AND** you use the online form **AND** you submit prior to your visa's expiry **AND** the fee is collected prior to your visa's expiry **AND** you select premium service **AND** your premium service appointment is beyond your visa's expiry.then they will forgive the overstay gap between successive T2 visas.  This was confirmed by the Business Help Desk last year and you can use them to confirm it for yourself also.